# How to add insert more than one record into table using MSAccess query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've tried this

```
INSERT INTO Table_1(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4,Col_5, Col_6)
VALUES('Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4','Date_1','Value_5'),('Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4','Date_1','Value_5');
```

But it states that there's a missing semicolon at the end of the sentence

I've also tried

```
INSERT INTO Table_1(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4,Col_5, Col_6)
VALUES(('Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4','Date_1','Value_5'),('Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4','Date_1','Value_5'));
```

But i get syntax error (comma)

Comment: Just use separate `insert` statements.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff that worked!!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

INSERT INTO Table_1(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4,Col_5, Col_6)

SELECT 'Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4','Date_1','Value_5'

UNION

SELECT 'Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4','Date_1','Value_5';

Comment: @cypher Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO T1 (C1,C2,C3) 
SELECT A,B,C FROM (
  SELECT 'A1' AS A,'B1' AS B,'C1' AS C FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources)   UNION
  SELECT 'A2','B2','C2' FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources) 
)
```

1st to know is, that you need a table with one line

```
**(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources)**
```

So you can select each constant value from this single- row- table (you can use ANY table, not only MSysResources. By using count(*) you shrink this to one row)

Now you can put all your values into this line:

```
SELECT 'A1' AS A,'B1' AS B,'C1' AS C, COUNT(*) AS COUNTED FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSysResources)
```

This row will contain 3 constant values (and the count- value, but there is no need to do this)

By using **UNION** you can put more than one line together.
And to get it into the form

```
INSERT INTO my_table (COL1, COL2 ...) SELECT VAL1, VAL2, VAL3 FROM another_table
```

you can put the comlete union- query inside 2 brackets and use this as another_table

Maybe there is a better way to do your work, this looks strange, but works.