# How do I append a table into another with an additional record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following append query which takes the records from `tblAdgIEH` and appends them to `DD_ADG_Decision`

```
INSERT INTO DD_ADG_Decision ( AID, ADGID, DecisionID )
SELECT NAA.AID, tblAdgIEH.fldDgmId AS ADGID, 11 AS DecisionID
FROM tblAdgIEH, NAA
WHERE (((NAA.ATypeId)=1));
```

I would be able to add an extra record within the same query.
The extra record is:

| AID | ADGID | DecisionID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 77 | 11 |

I couldn't find any solution on the internet, so I am not sure if this is even possible without creating a second query.

**EDIT**
I tried the following as suggested in the links provided by some of the comments but I cant get this to work: `"syntax error (missing operator)"`

```
**INSERT INTO DD_ADG_Decision ( AID, ADGID, DecisionID )
SELECT NAA.AID, tblAdgIEH.fldDgmId AS ADGID, 11 AS DecisionID
FROM tblAdgIEH, NAA
WHERE (((NAA.ATypeId)=1))
UNION FROM tblAdgIEH
SELECT 1,2,3**
```

and I tried

```
**INSERT INTO DD_ADG_Decision ( AID, ADGID, DecisionID )
SELECT NAA.AID, tblAdgIEH.fldDgmId AS ADGID, 11 AS DecisionID
FROM tblAdgIEH, NAA
WHERE (((NAA.ATypeId)=1))
UNION SELECT 1,2,3**
```

Comment: You would use a UNION ALL of your SELECT with a row of contant values. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410919/ms-access-database-multiple-rows-of-static-constant-data or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982959/how-to-add-insert-more-than-one-record-into-table-using-msaccess-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add insert more than one record into table using MSAccess query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982959/how-to-add-insert-more-than-one-record-into-table-using-msaccess-query)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but these solutions do not seem to work in my situation (see edit in post)

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the UNION query must be a valid SELECT statement too.

```
INSERT INTO DD_ADG_Decision ( AID, ADGID, DecisionID )
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT NAA.AID, tblAdgIEH.fldDgmId AS ADGID, 11 AS DecisionID
    FROM tblAdgIEH, NAA
    WHERE (((NAA.ATypeId)=1))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS AID, 77 AS ADGID, 11 AS DecisionID
    FROM DummyTableWithOneRecord
)
```

Using `UNION ALL` is faster and prevents possible side effects.

Note: The UNION ALL query works by itself as SELECT query, but to use it in an INSERT query, you must encapsulate it into a subquery - see edit.

Comment: It looked promising, but getting a syntax error (missing operator) shown on this line `(((NAA.ATypeId)=1))
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS AID, 77 AS ADGID, 11 AS DecisionID
FROM DummyTableWithOneRecord`

Comment: You're right - see edit. @MK01111000

Comment: Access now gives an error `The microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input or query 'DummyTableWithOneRecord', Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.`

Comment: Well, that was an example. :) Either create a dummy table with one record, or use the method from one of the linked questions to use a system table. @MK01111000